# iOS: No result from CoreML prediction, using model converted from Keras

Tags: ios, tensorflow, keras, coreml, machine-learning-model

The problem I'm facing is in Xcode 9 (*Beta 5*) my model's prediction call doesn't give any result, just hangs there, without error.

The requirement is to recognize one specific movement of user's phone, and exclude other similar movements. So my input is the data from accelerometer for x, y, z directions individually, and output is [positiveProbability, negativeProbability].

Originally my model was written with TensorFlow backend, I then transformed it to Keras model and converted to CoreML model. (*TensorFlow-1.1.0  Keras-2.0.6  Protobuf-3.4.0*)

Here is the python code of my model:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(123)  # for reproducibility
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten
from keras.layers import Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.utils import np_utils
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras import backend as K
from keras.optimizers import sgd
import json
from data_fetcher import pre_process_data
import coremltools
print K.image_data_format()

def process_data(datafile):
  with open(datafile) as data_file:
    data = json.load(data_file)
  if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_last':
    # NHWC: tensorflow backend, always channel last
    _x = np.zeros(shape=(len(data), 200, 3, 1))
    _y = np.zeros(shape=(len(data), 2))

for i in range(len(data)):
    output = pre_process_data(data, i)
    output.data_process()
    output.fft()
    #output.plot_curve('Walk')
    temp = [output.acceHFX, output.acceHFY, output.acceHFZ]
    temp = np.transpose(temp)
    temp = np.reshape(temp, (200, 3, 1))
    label = output.string
    if label == 'Pattern1' or label == 'Pattern2':
      l = np.array([[1., 0.]])
    else:
      l = np.array([[0., 1.]])
    _x[i] = temp
    _y[i] = l
# shuffle the data set (_x,_y shuffle according to the same order)
c = list(zip(_x,_y))
np.random.shuffle(c)
_x1,_y1 = zip(*c)
Data = (np.asarray(_x1), np.asarray(_y1))
return Data

def deepnn():
  # 7. Define model architecture
  model = Sequential()

  # below is the model given by tensorflow example:
  model.add(Convolution2D(10, (5, 1), activation='relu', input_shape=(200, 3, 1))) # a stack of 10 H*W =200*3 images
  model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(5, 1))) # reduce size to (10,40,3)
  model.add(Convolution2D(20, (5, 1), activation='relu')) # a stack of 20 40*3 images
  model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(5, 1))) # reduce size to (20,8,3)
  model.add(Dropout(0.25))

  model.add(Flatten()) # flatten to be 20*8*3
  model.add(Dense(50, activation='relu')) # fully connected layer shrink down to 50 features
  model.add(Dropout(0.5))
  model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax')) # map 50 features to 2 classes

  # 8. Compile model
  SGD = sgd(lr=0.05, decay=0.0, momentum=0.0, nesterov=False)
  model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
          optimizer='SGD',
          metrics=['accuracy'])
  return model

# 9. Fit model on training data

def main():
  model = deepnn()
  filename = 'datacollector-07182017Combined.json'
  xData = process_data(filename)
  testing_size = 0.25 # reserve 20 percent for testing
  num_inputs = len(xData[0])
  cutoff = int((1.0-testing_size)*num_inputs)
  x_train = xData[0][:cutoff]
  y_train = xData[1][:cutoff]
  x_test = xData[0][cutoff:]
  y_test = xData[1][cutoff:]
  model.fit(x_train, y_train,batch_size=5, epochs=8, verbose=1)

  # 10. Evaluate model on test data
  score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=0)
  print score

  coreml_model = coremltools.converters.keras.convert(model)
  coreml_model.save('model.mlmodel')

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

It's a sequential model with shape 200x3x1. After importing to Xcode it looks like this:
[image]

Here is the code in my iOS project to construct input:

```
private typealias Accelerate = (x: Double, y: Double, z: Double)

private func transformToModelInput(data: [Accelerate]) -> MLMultiArray {
    guard let input = try? MLMultiArray(shape:[1,200,3], dataType:MLMultiArrayDataType.double) else {
        fatalError("Unexpected runtime error. MLMultiArray")
    }

    var dataArray = data.map { $0.x }
    dataArray += data.map { $0.y }
    dataArray += data.map { $0.z }

    for (index, value) in dataArray.enumerated() {
        input[index] = NSNumber(floatLiteral: value)
    }

    return input
}
```

Here is my prediction codes:

```
let input = transformToModelInput(data: sampledData)

do {
    let output = try model.prediction(input1: input)
    let multiArray = MultiArray<Double>.init(output.output1)

    if multiArray[0] > multiArray[1] {
        print("Prediction: POSITIVE  \(multiArray)")
    } else {
        print("Prediction: NEGATIVE  \(multiArray)")
    }
} catch let error {
    print("CoreML Prediction Failed: \(error)")
}
```

However, the model.prediction call never gives any results, the project just hangs there forever. I really need helps on figuring out what's wrong, or at least how to debug the issue.

Comment: Are you sure there is not a blue arrow on the line with model.prediction (i.e. you've inadvertently set a breakpoint). If that's not the case and the app doesn't appear to do anything, then press the pause button to drop into the debugger. This will give you the stackframe of what's currently happening. That would be a good place to start debugging (although if it's a bug in Core ML there's not much you can do about it).

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think we can debug inside CoreML prediction. It's kind of black box for developers.

Comment: Indeed. However, I just wanted to make sure that the hang really was inside Core ML rather than your own code somewhere.